# Nokogiri: Root element in XML which isn't called 'root'

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new to create a structure whose root element is called 'file' rather than 'root'.

All of the examples on the Nokogiri documentation site use `<root>`, and I can't seem to find a way to get it to work with an alternative element name. My code is as follows:

```
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
xml.file(:id_=> "", :format=> "", :mimetype=>"", :size=>""){
    xml.location(:type=>"")
    xml.checksum(:type=>"")
    }
```

That doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what's going wrong. Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited to put backquotes around `<root>` in your text. Otherwise it becomes invisible.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" = ? What is the behavior observed? The top-level element is still named `<root>` instead of `<file>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me..

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new {|b| b.file }.to_xml
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<file/>\n" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Nokogiri::VERSION
 => "1.4.4"
```